# Can we solve for the limit of the function?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the function $y(x)=6 \arctan(e^{\frac{x}{3}- \frac{\ln(3)}{2}})$. How would I find the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$? I plotted this on desmos and it seems it becomes a constant function with value $3\pi$, but I'm not sure how or why. I want to find $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} y(x)$$

Comment: $6\arctan (\infty)=6(\frac {\pi} 2)=3\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, you need to further understand the function $\arctan x$ by its definition.

Anyway we know that:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\frac{x}{3}-\frac{\ln3}{2}}=\infty,\;\;\;\;\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

By substitution we get: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}6\arctan\left(e^{\frac{x}{3}-\frac{\ln3}{2}}\right)\underset{t=e^{\frac{x}{3}-\frac{\ln3}{2}}}{=}\lim_{t\to\infty}6\arctan t=3\pi$$

Comment: is the notation $\arctan (\infty)$ normal? I have never seen that before

Comment: As we can't plug in $\infty$ into a function, this notation is a shorter way to emphasis that $\arctan x$ is continuous, namely the limit of $\arctan y$ is $\arctan (y_0)$ as $y$ approaches $y_0$. I can also add the longer way without this notation, if you wish.

Comment: Please see my edit, I removed this notation.